# Char matrix send as param

Tags: c, pointers

If i create a

char a[100][100];

and send to a function void func(char** a);
It says that a char (*)[100] cannot be converted to char **.

I imagined that a char [100][100] is like a pointer to pointer.
Was i wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It decays into a pointer to an array of 100 characters.

Comment: how should i declare the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you were wrong indeed. a `char[100][100]` is an array of (array of 100 `char`), and when passing it to a function, it is converted to a pointer to (array of 100 `char`), a `char (*)[100]`. The conversion of arrays to pointers when passed as function arguments only affects the outermost level of arrays.

You could either declare the function as taking a parameter of that type,

```
void func(char (*)[100]);
```

if you will always pass arrays with 100 columns, or you would have to pass a different argument if you want to keep the function's type.

Comment: how should i declare the function?

Comment: Prototype now added, but if you want to pass arrays of varying dimensions (the row number is unimportant, but the column number counts), you need to do it differently. What is your use case?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep it simple and declare it like this:

```
void func(char a[100][100]);
```

If your system supports variable length arrays, you can do something like this:

```
void func(int nRows, int nCols, char a[nRows][nCols]);
```

The second method allows you to pass any sized two-dimensional array to the function.